# Method name is striked

Tags: android

In eclipse some times method name gets striked like this

ObjectName.<strike>methodName();</strike>

Why it happen like this please can any one explain this

Thanks.

Comment: looks like its deprecated

Comment: That's a feature of eclipse/lint.  It means the method is deprecated.  You can still use it and it will generally still work, but there may be better ways of doing it now.  Generally I don't worry about it when I see it, other than to throw a lint annotation on it to get rid of the effect

Comment: Because that method is deprecated.

Comment: it means that method is deprecated. Still you can use but better method is already available to by pass this method.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the old methods **deprecated** in Eclipse, code becomes difficult to read because the “**strikethrough**” is marked with in the default setting.

At development of Java (Including Android), to turn off the “strikethrough” for the deprecated method is as easy as following.

- Open the menu Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Colorling
- In Element, select “Deprecated members“
- Remove the check mark of Enable
- Click Apply

[**Reference**](http://www.devlog.en.alt-area.org/?p=697)